# What is a good way to organize and maintain predictive model input features in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, machine-learning, prediction

Consider a toy forum database with tables like User, Post, Votes, etc.

Assume that we have a machine-learning system for classifying users based on some features. The features were engineered by a team of modelers and may include values directly from the User column (say, `user_age`), as well as more complicated queries, which may require aggregations over linked tables (say, `vote_count_for_latest_post` or `number_of_posts_with_positive_votes`, etc).

Assume there may be hundreds of such features, which may used in different models for various purposes. All the features are recomputed in a single offline huge table daily for the modelers. The modelers may then select, say, 10-20 features to be used in a production model. The features for the production model would be computed on-line at the time of the query.

What would be a reasonably convenient and efficient way to organize and maintain such features.

To explain what I mean, consider three options:

- Maintain the large "offline table" generation script, which contains all the logic for feature computation. Cherry-pick the necessary pieces of this script into a stored procedure which is used in production.
  This is good in that both offline table generation script and the storedproc may be made rather efficient - we can only join the necessary secondary tables once and have all the aggregations done on them in one place.
  The bad part is this approach is very hard to maintain because there is no modularity in how and where the features are defined. You cannot often simply copy-paste a part of the "offline" script into an "on-line" proc, because the `select`s and `join`s may be structured differently in the two.
- Maintain each feature as a scalar user-defined function of `user_id`. This provides maximum modularity and makes both the on-line and off-line scripts very straightforward, but it would probably make the offline table computation rather slow - if 100 features require aggregation over the same table, chances are the server might not be smart enough to avoid 100 extra traversals (did not test myself, though)
- Maintain groups of related features as table-valued user-defined functions or views. This might provide a good compromise between efficiency and maintainability.

Although my personal preference seems to be the latter option, I wonder whether I am inventing the wheel here. Perhaps there are established solutions for this problem out there already?